# Is there any PyPSA sample of the Energy Storage capacity expansion model?

Tags: expansion, capacity, pypsa

We are trying to study a closed Li-B capacity expansion PyPSA model in South Korea.

There were a few samples online, but they were all in Europe and quite different from the power system I wanted to implement.
I would like to study a model with the objective of minimizing the total cost between ESS facilities and operation for one year in the future (2030).

I'm looking for samples that include power demand balancing constraints, output limit constraints, HVDC transmission constraints, and ESS charging/discharging upper and lower limit constraints.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good start:

https://fneum.github.io/data-science-for-esm/10-workshop-pypsa-cem.html

There is energy storage added at the end of the example.

Comment: Thanks for your recommend!.

But I already found that.. Is there other examples??